# Titanium orientationchange event does not fire

Tags: titanium

I have an iOS application developed using Titanium. I am using the orientationchange event to re-layout some views when the orientation changes.

This is how the event is registered in alloy.js:

```
Ti.API.info("Registering orientationchange");

Ti.Gesture.addEventListener('orientationchange',function(e) {
    Titanium.API.info("Orientation change detected . isPortrait= " + e.source.isPortrait() );
    Titanium.App.fireEvent('orient', {portrait:e.source.portrait});
});
```

Then I listen for the 'orient' event in my views to perform the layout changes.

This worked just fine before, using Ti SDK 7.5 and iOS 12. It stopped working after having updated to Ti SDK 8.2 and iOS 13.1.

Now however, I just get the "Registering orientationchange" printout in the console, but the registered callback is never called.

I cannot find anything in the release notes, and the event is still documented in the Ti SDK online documentation.

Anyone found a reason or workaround for this?

Comment: could you try 8.0.0.GA please? There was a big change in 8.1.0 (https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/pull/10381) that touched the Gesture class too. Perhaps something went wrong there. I only get one orientation change

Comment: You are correct, the event is triggered correctly using 8.0.0.GA

Comment: could you file a bug report with the findings at https://jira.appcelerator.org/ Looks like you've found a bug!

Comment: Seems this issue has never been fixed. I am dealing with it now. I created a Jira ticket for it. https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/AC-6525